# Azure DevOps repo API list files or commits in PR

Tags: azure-devops, azure-repos

Working on a huge repo with lots of activity all day, I'm trying to figure a method to get the list of files from chained commits on a branch via API. Doing it via git operations is causing me huge pain.

When one creates a pull request in the web UI as in "Create a pull request" then click "Files", Azure has exact knowledge of the commits and files. I am looking for a way to emulate this, ideally without creating the pull request. If I can get the commit hashes, that too would work.

Answer (score 0):

You may try [Diffs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/diffs/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP). There is an example for branches (you may compare source and target branches): [Between branches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/diffs/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP#between-branches)

Answer (score 0):

@ Shamrai Aleksander  has given the reference doc:[Diffs](https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Frest%2Fapi%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fgit%2Fdiffs%2Fget%3Fview%3Dazure-devops-rest-7.1%26tabs%3DHTTP%23between-commit-ids&data=05%7C01%7Cv-douxu%40microsoft.com%7Cf7754284c3f647066eb508dac6cd79a4%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C638040883064403761%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C3000%7C%7C%7C&sdata=BPIYo9j%2F4Gljds066MsiGLYG4r0d1%2F%2BJWAXsuhMR0BI%3D&reserved=0). On the basis of his answer, I test the REST API in postman and it works.

For example:

URL:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{your organization}/{your project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId} /diffs/commits?baseVersion={basecommitId}&baseVersionType=commit&targetVersion={targetCommitID}&targetVersionType=commit&api-version=7.1-preview.1
```

Test in postman:
[image: test in postman]

In the response body, you can get the differ between the base and target commits. `changes`  include the file path and changeType and other detailed information

Comment: How the issue is going ?  If it helps, just a remind of accept an answer.  If not, i‘ll stay focused on your issue.